# R Code for Yeo-Johnson transformation

Tags: r, data-transformation

I have writen code for a Box-Cox transformation (see below). But now I want to do a Yeo-Johnson transformation because `datc$plot` contains zeros. I tried, but I didn't find a solution.

```
lambda.fm1 <- boxcox(datc$plot ~ datc$cond.evlot*datc$cond.dl*datc$version), 
                     family="yjPower")
lambda.max <- lambda.fm1$x[which.max(lambda.fm1$y)]
require(car)
datc$plott <- bcPower(datc$plot, lambda = lambda.max, jacobian.adjusted = FALSE)
```

Comment: in the first line I don`t write "family="yjPower".

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to the site. You don't have to code it yourself. The Yeo-Johnson transformations are implemented in the [`car` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) with the function `yjPower`. So just use `yjPower(datc$plot, lambda=lambda.max, jacobian.adjusted=FALSE)`. I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks @ COOLSerdash I tried, but the problem is in the fist line:

Comment: lambda.fm1 <- boxcox(datc$plot, ... doesn´t work because  datc$plot contains zeros

Comment: Okay, then try to use the function `boxCox` from the `car` package and use it with the option `family="yjPower"`.

Comment: See the `yeo.johnson` [function](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/VGAM/html/yeo.johnson.html) in the package `VGAM` as well. It is on CRAN.

Answer (score 5):

From a recent update (2013, August 04<sup>th</sup>), [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) R package (see page 97) also supports Y-J power transformation.

Comment: I'm looking for the inverse of Yeo-Johnson Transformation in R. Could you please give a link on a package/function.